# How can i use Drag method to resize my application window?

Tags: testcomplete

How can i use Drag () method to resize my WPF application window? I am working on TestComplete 9 using Jscript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to resize a window is to call its [`Position`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/61100/) method:

```js
// JScript
var wnd = Sys.Process("notepad").Window("Notepad");
wnd.Position(150, 200, 600, 400);  // top, left, width, height
```

Comment: I get the error "Unable to find the object Position(lft, top, width, height) " when i specify the coordinates and run the script. ( I pickedup the coordinates from the Object spy)

Comment: @user2993178: It should be something like `Aliases.MyApp.MainWindow.Position(x, y, width, height);` Check the Object Spy to make sure your window object has the `Position` method (maybe you're applying `Position` to a wrong object).

Comment: @Helen :  You are right.My Window is a WPFObject. I dont see the Position method in the Object spy. Is there any other way to resize the window?

Comment: @user2993178: You're probably using a wrong `WPFObject` object. Open the Object Browser and find the object named `WPFObject("HwndSource: ....")` under your application process - this one is the window, and it will have the `Position` method.

Comment: @Helen : Brilliant! I used  a slightly wrong window object.It works now.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Helen: I am getting another issue.After resizing , i am not able to perform any action on the window as it says "Unable to find the object". How can i bring back the focus on the resized window? Iam using the same reference obj.So how can i resolve this reference clash?

Comment: @user2993178: Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask); comments are used to clarify answers, and not for extended discussion. Or try [vendor support](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) for assistance.